# In xcode -- how to easily switch editor view from 'swift-like' generated representation of header to underlying objective-c header

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

Xcode has the "helpful feature" (in quotes because its not helpful to me) of generating a swift-syntax representation of objective-c headers.

When using shortcuts to open a .h file (cmd-shift-o then type Foo.h) -- sometimes you are taken to the swift representation of Foo.h and sometimes to the objective-c representation.

The vast majority of the time, I want the objective-c representation -- is there a way to quickly switch to it with keyboard shortcuts when Xcode dumps you in the swift version?

Answer (score 5):

As of Xcode 9 (possibly before), you can select the "counterpart" from the four square menu. One is labeled as the swift representation, one is the ObjC representation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you are currently in a Swift file and open a header, you'll see the Swift-generated header. If you want to see the Objective-C version, you can open a .m file first, then open the header file.

Comment: This is technically correct -- however it's not actually a solution and very cumbersome.  I was looking for a way to quickly toggle between the swift and objective-c header.  The need to switch to another .m file only switch back to the desired .h is incredibly annoying.